# Sum of Absolute Differences - Dynamic base and collection

Tags: sql, recursion, combinations

Long time reader, first time poster. tldr; at bottom

I'm in need of calculating the Sum of Absolute Differences between a Static set of data points and dynamic combination base set.

SQL 2005

Problem:

Think of 10 circular magnets with Serial Numbers : 1,3,6,7,8,11,12,13,18,20
Each Magnet has 7 data points representing gauss measurements taken around the magnet using a gauss meter.

Because these measurements do not vary much WITHIN a given magnet, but can vary greatly BETWEEN two different magnets, I am trying to calculate SUM of absolute differences between a grouping of magnets.

I started by SUMMING the 7 data points and then comparing those SUMS to each other. You can quickly identify which TWO magnets are the closest by sorting by the smallest SAD. SUM(ABS(Magnet1_DataPoints - Magnet2_DataPoints))

The tricky part began when trying to find the N grouping of magnets with the smallest SAD. This turned into a Combinations C(n,r) problem with added complexity. I could have 40 magnets and need to pull a group of 8 with the smallest SAD. I could have 30 and need to pull 4 magnets. So, the dynamic nature of this problem enters as well.

I'm looking for some guidance on how to write this in SQL. So far, I've hit several walls, especially when trying to do it recursively via an SP. The data points were giving me grief when trying to process this through a CTE.

I've found many examples of recursive combination algorithms, but I'm having trouble adapting them to my very specific use-case.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

More important details:

1.) Magnet ID's will be unique integers and once consumed, will be flagged as "checked out" with a boolean 0/1 field.
2.) The gauss numbers will be decimal (18,2) to begin with.
3.) It's possible I will need separate procedures for the "quantity/grouping" of magnets if that's easier, i.e., 4,8,12 (most likely those are the increments they will be pulled in).
4.) Magnet/ID order matters. 1,2,3,4 is the same as 2,3,1,4 (identical combinations)
5.) Ideally, the output would be a list representing the grouping and total SAD, i.e. with a request of 3 magnets.

```
ID1, ID2, ID3,  SAD
36,   28,  29,  20.0
36,   28,  31,  22.00
34,   28,  29,  24.00
```

Table Example as requested:

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpMagTable ( IDOne int, TopMiddleOne decimal(18,2), TopLeftOne decimal(18,2), TopRightOne decimal(18,2), MiddleOne decimal(18,2), BotLeftOne decimal(18,2), BotRightOne decimal(18,2), BotMiddleOne decimal(18,2), checked int)


INSERT INTO #TmpMagTable 
SELECT 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0
UNION ALL SELECT 10,7,5,6,4,2,3,1,0
UNION ALL SELECT 19,4,2,5,7,3,6,1,0
UNION ALL SELECT 28,1,2,2,3,2,2,1,0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0
UNION ALL SELECT 11,8,6,7,5,3,4,2,0
UNION ALL SELECT 20,8,3,6,5,4,7,2,0
UNION ALL SELECT 29,3,2,2,1,2,2,3,0
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
UNION ALL SELECT 12,9,7,8,6,4,5,3,0
UNION ALL SELECT 21,3,4,7,9,5,8,6,0
UNION ALL SELECT 30,5,3,3,2,5,5,4,0
UNION ALL SELECT 4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0
UNION ALL SELECT 13,10,8,9,7,5,6,4,0
UNION ALL SELECT 22,7,5,8,4,6,9,10,0
UNION ALL SELECT 31,4,1,3,5,4,3,1,0
UNION ALL SELECT 5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0
UNION ALL SELECT 14,11,9,10,8,6,7,5,0
UNION ALL SELECT 23,5,6,9,11,7,10,8,0
UNION ALL SELECT 32,3,4,6,2,4,1,2,0
UNION ALL SELECT 6,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,0
UNION ALL SELECT 15,12,10,11,9,7,8,6,0
UNION ALL SELECT 24,9,7,10,6,8,11,12,0
UNION ALL SELECT 33,5,3,3,6,1,1,2,0
UNION ALL SELECT 7,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,0
UNION ALL SELECT 16,13,11,12,10,8,9,7,0
UNION ALL SELECT 25,7,8,11,13,9,12,10,0
UNION ALL SELECT 34,1,3,3,0,2,1,5,0
UNION ALL SELECT 8,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,0
UNION ALL SELECT 17,14,12,13,11,9,10,8,0
UNION ALL SELECT 26,8,9,12,14,10,13,11,0
UNION ALL SELECT 35,6,1,3,1,0,0,2,0
UNION ALL SELECT 9,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0
UNION ALL SELECT 18,15,13,14,12,10,11,9,0
UNION ALL SELECT 27,12,10,13,9,11,14,15,0
UNION ALL SELECT 36,1,3,2,5,3,2,1,0
```

tldr; Need a recursive combination algorithm to sum values of each unique combination

Comment: Thanks. Updated with formatting and included my Tmp table and loading of data for 36 magnets.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?